# How can I break an if when a variable changes

Tags: c, pic

I need help I have this basic basic program to play with LEDs in a sequence of them depending on what switch I push, what I would like to know is: How can I interrupt one (or stop it) and run the other sequency when I toggle other switch and run the new sequency but not the  one before, I was wondering how other programs that need to abort actions do it, since it will be in the "loop" with delays and stuff, I guess that putting an if between lines in each led on and off would do it, but I don't think that's the correct/efficient way.. thanks!

```
#include <16f876.h>
#use delay(clock=4M)
#fuses XT,NOWDT
#use standard_io(A)
#use standard_io(B)

int16 t0=2000;
int16 t1=1000;
int16 t2=1000;
int16 t3=500;

void main(){
   output_b(0b00000000);
   while(TRUE){
      if(input(PIN_A0)==0){   
         output_b(0b00000000);
         output_b(0b00011000);
         delay_ms(t0);
         output_b(0b00100100);
         delay_ms(t0);
         output_b(0b01000010);
         delay_ms(t0);
         output_b(0b10000001);
         delay_ms(t0);
      }
      if(input(PIN_A1)==0){
         output_b(0b00000000);
         output_b(0b00000001);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b00000011);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b00000111);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b00001111);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b00011111);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b00111111);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b01111111);
         delay_ms(t1);
         output_b(0b11111111);
         delay_ms(t1);
      }
      if(input(PIN_A2)==0){
         output_b(0b10000000);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11000000);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11100000);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11110000);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11111000);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11111100);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11111110);
         delay_ms(t2);
         output_b(0b11111111);
         delay_ms(t2);
      }
      if(input(PIN_A3)==0){
         output_b(0b00000000);
         output_b(0b00000001);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000011);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000111);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00001111);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00011111);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00111111);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b01111111);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b00000000);
         delay_ms(t3);
         output_b(0b11111111);
         delay_ms(t3);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can there be multiple lights on at the same time, or only one at a time? What happens if instead of using 3 if statements, you use an if/else branch?

Comment: it's one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own delay_ms function something like this:

```
bool my_delay_ms(int mstime) {
    int current = 0;
    while (current < mstime) {
        delay_ms(10);
        current += 10;
        if (something?) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then replace every delay_ms with `if (my_delay_ms(t0)) continue;`.

You can change the 10 to however frequently you want to poll for the interrupt signal. The condition detects the interrupt signal, and the `continue` allows your while loop to jump to the next cycle to change the sequence if appropriate.

Comment: Hi,thanks for answering, I have a question, does the "if(my_delay_ms(t0)) continue;" actually waits for the time I set it up?or does it check either is true or false in that precise moment and goes to the next line? I have that doubt..

Comment: It will evaluate the entire function before exiting the function. If the interrupt flag is never true, the function runs for the whole time, if it exits early, it will trigger the continue statement.

Comment: simple and worked!, Although I had to use an int instead of a boolean(bool doesn't exist here; and return 1 and 0) , and for t0,t1,t2,t3 and mstime I had to declared them as an int16(Idk the reason but with just int the time went 10x faster, even though int16 and int are technically the same...) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a timer that triggers every millisecond, then rewrite the code as a state machine. That way you don't waste cpu cycles in delay routines, and you're able to respond to button presses immediately, well at least within a millisecond, which to the user is immediate.

The state machine keeps track of a variable. The number represents the state it's in. Each time a state is executed, the state may change. The changed state is executed the next time the timer triggers. Each trigger also checks buttons/debouncing etc.

Make sure your code runs within the timer period, so don't use any delays but use the state machine to do the delays, or another timer if you need a different resolution/timing.

I'll leave it up to you to setup the timer and interrupt registers.

```
  /* global variables */
  int state = 0;
  unsigned char delaycnt = 0;
  char millisecond_flag = 0;

  void DoStateMachine()
  {    
     switch( state )
     {
        case 100:
           output_b(0b00000000);
           output_b(0b00011000);
           state++;
           delaycnt = 10;
           break;
        case 101:
           delaycnt--;
           if(delaycnt == 0) state = 102;
           break;
           case 200:
           output_b(0b00000000);
           output_b(0b00000001);
           state++;
           delaycnt = 10;
           break;
        case 201:
           delaycnt--;
           if(delaycnt == 0) state = 202;
           break;
        default: 
           state = 0; // do nothing
           break;
      }
  }

  void CheckButtons()
  {
     // Do button debounce here
     if( BUTTON1 == 1)
        state = 100;
     if( BUTTON2 == 1) 
        state = 200;
  }

  void main()
  {
     //Setup timer here

     while(1)
     {
        if( millisecond_flag == 1)
        {
           CheckButtons();
           DoStateMachine();
           millisecond_flag = 0;
        }
        //sleep device?
     }
  }

  // Handle interrupt
  void interrupt ISR()
  {
     if( TMR1IF == 1)
     {
        millisecond_flag = 1;
        TMR1IF = 0;
     }
  }
```